# Can I disable the Thinkpad Ultranav driver for Windows 8.1? (use PS2 Mouse Driver instead)

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, touchpad, thinkpad

I had the older driver working exactly the way that I want it to on my Lenovo Twist. Unfortunately,  it's been driving me nuts ever since I upgraded to 8.1. I want it to work like a mouse. I was able to disable gestures with no problem but the one feature that I would like to disable has no option for that. I would like to disable the driver. Permanently.

I keep uninstalling it, when I do, my trackpad works like a mouse, exactly the way I want it. Of course it keeps re-installing itself. How do I stop this?

Comment: A clear title goes a long way in making people read your question. With a title like 'I hate the thinkpad Ultranav driver for 8.1' - you would have made people not got through the click at all

Comment: On the contrary, it helps the OP make a better question. I'd also ask what is the current and previous versions they've had.

Comment: Were the other comments that were here removed? As a first time user here, I really appreciated the support that I received from other users after the extremely unhelpful moderator here. It's great that he wanted me to "make a better question", not so great the snotty response and the downrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the tool [DriverStore Explorer](https://driverstoreexplorer.codeplex.com/) to remove the Touchpad driver from the Driverstore, [disable the Option to search on Windows Update for drivers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730606%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and now Windows can't install the driver again.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I found a great tutorial here on this question: http://superuser.com/questions/665158/can-i-prevent-a-driver-from-being-installed-with-windows-8-1?rq=1