# Can I defer only certain updates that won't install on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I can not seem to get several windows updates to install on my Windows 10 PC, so I want to block them, something you used to be able to do easily in the UI, but it appears these UI elements are gone from Windows 10.    I do NOT want to disable ALL UPDATES like [this guy](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-automatic-updates-windows-10), only certain ones.

Updates `KB3002340, KB2932965, KB2938807,  KB2645410, KB2635973` (mostly Visual Studio related), have been downloaded, and installation has started and failed, repeatedly.  In previous versions of Windows you could move an update to a "don't try to install this", uncheck a checkbox for this update, or something equivalent to that. You can no longer do this via any visual/ui element I can find in Windows 10. I'm hoping there's a registry tweak or a utility I could run that I could use to at least defer these updates for a while, since it appears that Our Wise and Noble Overlords at Microsoft Have Decided That You Shall Install All Updates, Even Ones that Won't Install, Over And Over Again, and Ye Shall Not Disable Them, Ever, Because Satya Nadella Hath Spoken, Neither Shall Ye Own or Control Your Computer For It Belongeth To Us And We Shall Do Whatever We Wantses With It.

Comment: These UI elements do not exist in windows 10.

Comment: Some what relevant (although not an answer) http://superuser.com/questions/901803/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-updating-a-specific-driver

Comment: No you cannot permanently block them like you could in previous versions of windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping automatic updates windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-automatic-updates-windows-10)

Comment: Slightly different question, since I don't want to stop all updates, only certain updates.  One of the non-accepted answers on that question answers the question.  I don't want to stop ALL automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

Found this tool at Microsoft support, which can defer items for a period of time, and may need to be repeated periodically:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930

Nevermind the first part of this article, near the end it offers the download of a tool that will let you hide updates, at least for a while.

Click the link that says

```
Download the "Show or hide updates" troubleshooter package now.
```

Comment: This only defers the update for a period of time, it will eventually install automatically.

Comment: If any microsoft people read this question; You goofed, this was a horrible decision.  Sometimes updates contain regressions and you should let users block updates permanently.