# Stop AMD drivers from updating

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card

How can I prevent Windows 10 from updating AMD video card drivers? I ask, because it installs the old drivers from 15.07, and with them my laptop starts to shut down one minute after I turn it on.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also: http://superuser.com/questions/947706/make-windows-10-stop-installing-driver-software-automatically, http://superuser.com/questions/954184/disable-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-10, and http://superuser.com/questions/901803/prevent-windows-10-from-installing-updating-a-specific-driver